# Montar em PHP um sistema de busca por período

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Criei um formulário com objetivo de pesquisar o nome da pessoa e com o campo de data início e data fim, com a intenção de pegar do banco a quantidade de atendimento dentro de um mês para essa pessoa pesquisada. Consegui montar para buscar o total, utilizando SUM no campo, porém não consigo achar uma forma de associar a pesquisa por data, segue o código que eu estou tentando montar:

Tabela [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1º arquivo

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1/AppAtendimentoFisioterapia/php/sistema/relatorio.php">
    Fisioterapeuta:<input type="text" name="buscar" size="50"placeholder="Informe o nome do(a) fisioterapeuta"><br><br>


<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Período Inicial</label>
         <input name="dtAtendimentoinicial" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" aria-label="State">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm mb-3">
         <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Período Final</label>
         <input name="dtAtendimentofinal" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" aria-label="State"><br><br>


         <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

2º arquivo:

```
<?php 

            
            $buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
            $dtInicial = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['dtAtendimentoinicial']));
            $dtFinal = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['dtAtendimentofinal']));

            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nmfisioterapeura, SUM(vlreceber), date_format(dtatendimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dtatendimento FROM registroatendimento WHERE nmfisioterapeura Like '%'.$buscar.'%' AND BETWEEN '$dtInicial' AND '$dtFinal'");

          
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            if ($row > 0) {
              while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                  $nomeFisio = $linha['nmfisioterapeura'];
                  $valorReceber = $linha['SUM(vlreceber)'];
                  $dtI = $linha['dtatendimento'];
                  $dtF = $linha['dtatendimento'];
                  
                }

              }
                    ?>

                    <tr style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;">    
                      <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $nomeFisio ?></td>
                      <td align="left" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $valorReceber ?></td>
                      <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $dtInicial ?></td>
                      <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $dtFinal ?></td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente a seguinte instrução de código

```php
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nmfisioterapeura, SUM(vlreceber), date_format(dtatendimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dtatendimento FROM registroatendimento WHERE nmfisioterapeura Like '%'.$buscar.'%' AND BETWEEN '$dtInicial' AND '$dtFinal' GROUP BY dtatendimento");
```

Documentação do cláusula `GROUP BY` no MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Eu alterei, mas continua com erro: Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppAtendimentoFisioterapia\php\sistema\relatorio.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\AppAtendimentoFisioterapia\php\sistema\relatorio.php(18): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppAtendimentoFisioterapia\php\sistema\relatorio.php on line 18

Comment: `mysqli_query` retorna `false` em caso de falha https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php . Recomendo depurar o código, pegar o valor passado no segundo parâmetro da função `mysqli_query` e executar o no phpMyAdmin para descobrir onde está o erro na consulta. Pode ser uma das variáveis que na concatenação não tinha valor. Recomendo fortemente Prepared Statements https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php